# Best multiInsert way to add database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How is best way add to database multiInsert row?
E.g  I have array  and i would like add  all array  to database. I can create loop foreach and add all arrays.

```
 $array=['apple','orange'];
 foreach($array as $v) 
 {
   $stmt = $db->exec("Insert into test(fruit) VALUES ('$v')");
 }
```

And it's  work, but maybe  i should  use transaction? or  it do other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a prepared statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (fruit) VALUES ";
$sql .= implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($array), '(?)'));
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

The SQL will look like:

```
INSERT INTO test (fuit) VALUES (?), (?), (?), ...
```

where there are as many `(?)` as the number of elements in `$array`.

Doing a single query with many `VALUES` is much more efficient that performing separate queries in a loop.

If you have an associative array with input values for a single row, you can use  a prepared query like this:

```
$columns = implode(',', array_keys($array);
$placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO test($columns) VALUES ($placeholders)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array_values($array));
```

Comment: Ya, I know preparedstatement. You say it better way since add array in loop?

Comment: Ok, thanks, but i have one problem. Why it not working? 

$column=implode(',',array_keys($array));
$val=implode(',',''.array_values($array.''));
$sql = "INSERT INTO test ($column) VALUES ('$val')";

Comment: Why do you have `.''` after `$array`?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're doing without proper code formatting.

Comment: Take a look at `echo $sql;` to see if the query looks correct. Make sure all the values are quoted properly. You're also leaving yourself open to SQL injection. You really should use a prepared query.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to create a prepared query dynamically for an array containing a single row's data.

Comment: Ye, but   I now   need simple exec sql, witchout  sql-injection security. 
I now  not have  quoted  in values. my sql print; 
 INSERT INTO test (Name,surname) VALUES (apple,orange) 
He has problem  with quoted in values.

Comment: You need to put quotes around the values, since they're strings.

Comment: Use prepared statements even if you aren't worried about security. It just makes things easier, since you don't need to worry about quoting and escaping.

Comment: Ok i will, but  your edit code preparedStatment  throw exception 
 Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: I just made a change to use `array_values` in the execute call.

Comment: Yee, now working, thanks. One more question yet.  If i would like  insert  e.g  10x it same record I have to use loop  ?

Comment: That's the easiest way to do it. But you could also add multiple `(?, ?, ?)` values to the sql, and use `array_merge` to concatenate all the records.

Comment: Ok i understand  all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've done it is, in many ways, the worst option. So the good news is that any other way of doing it will probably be better. As it stands, the code may fail depending on what's in the data; consider:

```
$v="single ' quote";
$stmt = $db->exec("Insert into test(fruit) VALUES ('$v')");
```

But without knowing what your criteria are for "best", its rather hard to advise. Using a parametrised query with data binding, or as they are often described "prepared statements" is one solution to the problem described above. Escaping the values *appropriately* before interpolating the string is another (and is how most PHP implementations of data binding work behind the scenes) is another common solution.

Leaving aside the question of how you get the parameters into the SQL statement, then there is the question of performance. Each round trip to the database has a cost associated with it. And doing a single insert at a time also has a performance impact - for each query, the DBMS must parse the query, apply the appropriate concurrency controls, execute the query, apply the writes to the journal, then to the data tables and indexes then tidy up before it can return the thread of execution back to PHP to construct the next query.

Wrapping multiple queries in a transaction (you are using transactions already - but they are implicit and applied to each statement) can reduce some of the overhead I have described here, but can introduce other problems, the nature of which depends on which concurrency model your DBMS uses.

To get the data into the database as quickly as possible, and minimising index fragmentation, the "best" solution is to batch up multiple inserts:

```
$q="INSERT INTO test (fruit) VALUES ";
while (count($array)) {
    $s=$q;
    $j='';
    for ($x=0; $x<count($array) && $x<CHUNKSIZE; $x++) {
         $s.=$j." ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,
            array_shift($array)) . "')";
         $j=',';
    }
    mysqli_query($db,$s);
}
```

This is similar to Barmar's method, but I think easier to understand when you are working with more complex record structures, and it won't break with very large input sets.

Comment: he's using PDO, not mysqli.

Comment: Not stated as a requirement.