# UPDATE query using prepared statement with multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I need to perform the following query, but will be using a prepared statement.  Note that the quantity of the WHERE clauses will change based on the data being sent to the server.

```
UPDATE bla SET x=123
WHERE (y=4 AND z=3)
OR (y=12 AND z=13)
OR (y=13 AND z=13)
OR (y=25 AND z=23)
OR (y=37 AND z=33)
OR (y=39 AND z=13)
OR (y=44 AND z=23)
OR (y=54 AND z=33)
OR (y=84 AND z=23)
OR (y=94 AND z=23)
OR (y=99 AND z=33);
```

I could generate either of the following arrays:

```
$arr=[12,13,13,13,25,23,27,33,39,13,44,23,54,33,83,23,94,23,99,33];
```

or

```
$arr=[[12,13],[13,13],[25,23],[37,33],[39,13],[44,23],[54,33],[84,23],[94,23],[99,33]];
```

Would it be best to do this with a single UPDATE query, or 10 UPDATE queries for each pair?

If a single query, what would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql you can do tuples comparasion.

So you can do something like this

```
UPDATE bla 
SET x=123
WHERE (x,y) in ((12,13),(13,13),(25,23),(37,33),(39,13),(44,23),(54,33),(84,23),(94,23),(99,33))
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it with a single query that's constructed using `implode` and `array_map`.

```
$where = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($e) {
    return "(y = $e[0] AND z = $e[1])";
}, $arr);
$sql = "UPDATE bla SET x = 123 WHERE $where";
```

Comment: Thanks for the use of tubles, and the PHP as well.

Comment: Actually, I still wish to use a prepared statement, so I will just generate `(?,?)` and implode them with a `,`, right?  And then use my second array example?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702794/best-multiinsert-way-to-add-database-in-php/33702893#33702893 for something similar. It's doing `INSERT`, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: I will look at it.  Probably will use something like `str_repeat('(?,?),', count($long_array)/2-1) . '(?,?)'`